# Dataframe groupby into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know how can i do this simply :

i have a `DataFrame` with `4` columns, i want to `group by` the `3` first columns, get the result of the 4 based on the 3 others and create a column with a `''.join` of the 3 columns name.

An example will be easier :

`a.  |b.   |c.  |d.

name1|name2|name3|result.

name4|name5|name6|result2.`

I want to have a new dataframe that look like that :
UPDATE :

`|name1-name2-name3|name4-name5-name6|.
|result1 |result2 |
|result1 |result2 |
|result1 |result2 |
|result1 |result2 |
|result1 |result2 |`

NB_CLIENTS is my result 
I group by periodicity and country 
and for each month i have a result.

EXAMPLE :

`MONTH|PERIODICITY|NB_CLIENTS|COUNTRY
2019-05|    monthly|     872|   NL
2019-02|    monthly|     361|   IT
2019-02|    monthly|     214|   NL
2019-05|    monthly|     737|   IT`

Will become :

`MONTH|monthly-NL. |monthly-IT
2019-05|872.       |737
2019-02|214.       |361`

I tried this :

```
grouped = test.groupby([name1,name2,name3]).RESULT
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
for name_of_the_group, group in grouped:
    tmp[' '.join(name_of_the_group)] = group
```

but i get all `Nan` values,  I guess it's about a copy or something , I need to `reset_index` maybe ? but where

Thanks

Comment: Please check dupe, if nedd something else, let me know.

Comment: I saw this dupe ,but its not what i want .
Here he want to concat all the result in one row .
But me i want to concat all columns name in one column and put all the results under

Comment: So you need `df = pd.DataFrame({'-'.join(v): [k] for k, v in test.set_index('d').T.items()})` ?

Comment: I forgot to say one thing, i have many results in my frame.
So it needs to look like the update i made (results arent all the same . i didnt want to write 1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: Ok, please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - edit question.

Comment: So from 2 rows DataFrames is created 5 rows DataFrame with repeated data? Not understand logic here.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, i updated with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with flatten columns by `f-string`s:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='MONTH', 
                    columns=['PERIODICITY','COUNTRY'], 
                    values='NB_CLIENTS', 
                    aggfunc='sum')
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
     MONTH  monthly-IT  monthly-NL
0  2019-02         361         214
1  2019-05         737         872
```